# moderncv: Increase space between cventry

Tags: spacing, moderncv

I wrote my CV using `moderncv` but the entries (in particular `\cventry`) are too compact for me. I tried to change the `parskip` but it does not change anything.

Could you tell me how could I increase the spacing between the items?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

All the `\cv...` macros have an optional argument that specifies additional vertical space added after the item.
In the classic theme for example you find:

```
\renewcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
    ...
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

and `\cventry` is defined in terms of `\cvitem`:

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
      ...
```

So, to change the spacing of a particular entry you can do for example:

```
\cventry[2em]{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
```

## Edit: changing spacing globally

In case you want to adjust these spaces globally you can change `\parskip` but in order for that to be effective you have to change it **after** `\begin{document}` since `moderncv` sets it when the document begins, overriding any previous setting.

## Summary:

- To alter the spacing after a specific item use the optional argument as in `\cvitem[2em]{...`
- To alter the spacing globally change `\parskip` **after** `\begin{document}` using `\setlength{\parskip}{2em}`

(obviously `2em` is just an example, change accordingly!)

Comment: `\setlength{\parskip}{2em}` had to come after `\makecvtitle` for me to have an effect.

Comment: `\parskip` affects a lot more than just `\cventry` spacing. Any way to change it globally but limit it just to the end of `\cventry`?

Comment: In my case the above solution worked for `\cvlistitem` and `\cventry` but not for `\cvlanguage' nor `\cvline` In those cases a `\vspace` command at the end was necessary:  '\cvline{}{}\vspace{2ex}` and  `\cvlanguage{}{}{}\vspace{2ex}`